# Joining 3 tables with a junction table (HABTM)

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We have 3 tables - **items**, **locations** and **taxes**. *items_locations* and *locations_taxes* are already associated. But, there is a need to connect all of them - *items_locations_taxes*

Database schema is already in place. When I baked locations model, it did something like this :

```
$this->belongsToMany('LocationsTaxes', [
    'foreignKey' => 'location_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'locations_tax_id',
        'joinTable' => 'items_locations_taxes'
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Items', [
        'foreignKey' => 'location_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'item_id',
        'joinTable' => 'items_locations'
    ]);
    $this->belongsToMany('Taxes', [
        'foreignKey' => 'location_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'tax_id',
        'joinTable' => 'locations_taxes'
    ]);
```

First belongsToMany seems to be wrong. Its auto generated through Bake.
Now, how can these 3 be connected through join?

And, take a note that junction tables are using composite primary keys and do not contain id column.

Comment: But what is the problem? Why do you think it is wrong? Does `items_locations` and `locations_taxes` exist?

Comment: @JoséLorenzo locations_tax_id column doesn't exist. And the className there - 'LocationsTaxes' is already used as joinTable for Taxes. My requirement is to show location wise taxes on items page. An item can have multiple locations and a location can have multiple taxes and that is why I need to combine all of them.

Comment: Ok, if the column does not exist, why put it in the configuration? Just use the columns that exist

Comment: Well, as I said, Bake has generated this. Now, what I plan is to just remove the first belongsToMany altogether and fetch the taxes through location association i.e. Items->Locations->Taxes. Would that be a proper way to deal. José?

Comment: That sounds good to me